# iphone Read incoming SMS message

Tags: iphone, sms

I would like to know whether we can read the incoming **SMS** message in **iPhone**.
If any new **SMS** message arrives I want to open it through *my app*.

Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: Another solution would be to use the search function in Stack Overflow and/or Google.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible in iOS, sorry

Comment: And is good that apps can't, just think about the possible privacy issues this could cause.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone does not have any API hooks into the SMS stack. There is, however, a sqlite style database that you can read with the information inside. If the phone is jailbroken it can be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

No, on a non-jailbroken phone, you cannot get any data on SMS messages or phone calls. They are entirely walled off from your application.