# Read sms using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sms

I am trying to create a small sms app in swift. But I can seem to find anything in the documentation about receiving and reading SMS, I can only find a method to send sms's. Is there a way to receive SMS in iOS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone Read incoming SMS message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701530/iphone-read-incoming-sms-message)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't allowed to access SMS. Apple doesn't allow this.

Even if you would be able to achieve this, Apple wouldn't allow it to be in the App Store.

Comment: If there is no api to read incoming sms in iphone, then how is whatsapp activation code works while installation. FYI, While installing whatsapp in iphone, An activation code is sent to your entered mobile number which then automatically used by whatsapp for registration. So somehow they read the incoming sms and use it for registration. If it is the case, how is it done?

Comment: They are not reading the sms message. The last time i've activated it you had to type the code in yourself. Apple doesnt allow 3rd party apps to access that kind of API.

Comment: How does the Google Assistant app do this on iOS?